# How to change contents in parent div from child div?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to modify the text in the parent div from child div without changeing the child div contents.

I have

```
<div id='testDiv'>
    this is the test parent div
    <div id='child1'>
         lots of contents and child div
         ...................
    </div>
    more div/child div and contents...

</div>
```

in my jquery

```
$('child1 div a').click(function(){
    $('#testDiv').text('new text');  //this will remove the child1 div and all the contents inside testDiv
    //I want to replace 'this is the test parent div' text to 'newt text' 
})
```

Are there anyways to get this done? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the text in a span, it would be easier to change it:

```
$('#testDiv').contents()
             .filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3})
             .wrap($('<span />',{'class':'test'}));

$('.test').text('new text');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/szfrd/1/)

You could ofcourse unwrap the textnode once it's changed if the span element causes some sort of problem?
    ​

Comment: `{ id: "test" }` is a bad idea. Use classes instead.

Comment: @VisioN - It's just a basic way to show how to access the wrapping span, and has nothing to do with the classes/id's discussion ?

Comment: This code is not at all transparent, surely it makes more sense to clearly identify the piece of text that needs to change? After all, if it is identifiable it must have some semantic meaning and so the markup should reflect that.

Comment: @Nick - then please enlighten us as to how you suggest we select a textnode within an element ?

Comment: @adeneo It has. You receive multiple elements with the same IDs, which is a bad example.

Comment: @VisioN - I'm only targeting one textnode, but I'll change it to a class, even if that sort of defeats the purpose somewhat.

Comment: My answer has been down voted the most! But @Sushanth has not stated that it is not possible to change the contents of the outer div, just that the contents of the child div must not be changed. It understand that your code works but it seems the simplest solution has been overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a mix of `.filter()` and `.contents()`

```
$('#child1 div a').click(function() {
    $('#testDiv').contents().filter(function() {
        if (this.nodeType != 1 && this.data.trim() != '') {
            return this.data = 'New Text';
        }
        else {
            return this
        };
    });
})​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5atGZ/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `firstChild` property:

```
​document.getElementById('testDiv').firstChild.nodeValue = 'new text'​​;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vstHS/

Answer (score -2):

You just need to contain the portion that you want to change into another div and target that directly...

```
<div id='testDiv'>
    <div id='changeMe'>
        this is the test parent div
    </div>
    <div id='child1'>
         lots of contents and child div
         ...................
    </div>
    more div/child div and contents...
</div>
```

The jquery:

```
$('child1 div a').click(function(){
    $('#changeMe').text('new text');
})
```

Comment: Anyone willing to explain why they think is a bad idea / won't work?

Comment: You did not pay close enough attention to the requirements of the question, is my guess. `changeMe` is **not** the 'parent div' of `child1` in your example, so your code explicitly *does not do* what this question asked for.

Comment: I thought that too, but the question asks how to _modify the text in the parent div from child div without changeing the child div contents_. It does not say that the parent div cannot be amended.`changeMe` is not the parent div, but it is a child of the parent div.

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself; your solution does not do what was asked: It does *not* change the text of a parent div at all. Look at the other answers; that can quite easily be done. The fact that the user asked for a solution that changes the parent div without changing the child div suggests they... well; it suggests *what they asked for is what they need*.

Comment: If a child of a parent changes, is it not true that the parent has also changed? I think not: therefore the text of the parent div has changed even if the text is wrapped in a child element. The user made it clear that the contents of the child div should not change, but did not say that the html cannot be modified. Had that been stated and not merely implied then would I would not have answered. I understand that you _can_ change text nodes, but my answer is simpler than that.

Comment: Ok; we disagree about it, but I understand your argument. Just explaining why I think people down voted. (I didn't, btw)